When should sp_spaceused be used to get the size of a database, instead of querying sys.database_files?
I frequently find the output of sp_spaceused misleading. What appears to be the size of all data in a database is actually the combined size of both the data file and the log file. I have recently discovered sys.database_files and I have found it superior in every way. It is so much better than sp_spacedused that I am planning to drink until I forget about that procedure.
This give me my question: When checking the size of a database, is there any feature or return value offered by sp_spacedused that cannot be obtained from sys.database_files? I've checked over the documentation and I'm pretty sure that there isn't.

sp_spaceused is an older stored procedure. What it does have that sys.database_files doesn't is the free space available. I would suggest you use the dm views sys.dm_db_file_space_usage and sys.dm_db_log_space_usage instead.
SELECT
    'Data' AS FileType,
    FORMAT((SUM(total_page_count) * 1.0 / 128),'#,##0.0') AS [total space in MB],
    FORMAT((SUM(unallocated_extent_page_count) * 1.0 / 128),'#,##0.0') AS [free space in MB],
    FORMAT((SUM(unallocated_extent_page_count)*1.0/SUM(total_page_count) )*100.0,'0.0') AS [free space pct]
FROM sys.dm_db_file_space_usage
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'Log' AS FileType,
    FORMAT(total_log_size_in_bytes*1.0/1024/1024,'#,##0.0') AS [total space in MB] ,
    FORMAT((total_log_size_in_bytes - used_log_space_in_bytes)*1.0/1024/1024,'#,##0.0') AS [free space in MB],  
    FORMAT(100-used_log_space_in_percent,'0.0') AS [free space pct]
FROM sys.dm_db_log_space_usage;  


The dbatools wrapper for sys.databasefiles claims to give FreeSpaceMB. Is that somehow wrong?

No they just use an additional function, FILEPROPERTY(f.name, 'SpaceUsed') to get the usage of the data files - then they can calculate the free space
